# I cant login after installing 14.04 alongside vista

Tags: 14.04

I installed the latest ubuntu on a laptop that i have. It has windows vista. I put in the ubuntu disc i made and installed alongside vista. So i restart. Boot up ubuntu. I get to the login. Type my password login I told it to use on install. Ubuntu will not except. Is there a default login? Or a admin login i can use? Please help?

Comment: It must be the same password you used during install. Note that it is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is just a possibility :

You would have accidentally left the CAPS LOCK on during install. Try entering your password with CAPS LOCK turned on. This happened to be once. This might just work.

Comment: Or numlock, on a laptop this is quite likely too.

Comment: Possible. However I don't think any laptop users will use the numpad much. Atleast i don't.

Comment: Agreed: If there's a separate numpad. Most laptops don't have, desktops do - so the numeric keys are all across the yuiop side of the keyboard. This is a recurring problem where I work...